# Register a js file independently in Assets

Tags: yii2

I'm developing a module where I've some custom js functions to be use in a form inside a Dialog.
I successfully loaded as inline script in the view that launch the dialog that include the form with something like:

```
$script = <<< JS
var scheda=$("table#schedaTable");
var idtum=scheda.attr('idtum');

scheda.find("i.modifica.concessione").on('click', function() {
  $("#concessioneDialog").load("/cimiteriale/concessioni/edit-concessione?idtum="+idtum).dialog("open");
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script, $this::POS_END);
```

but for several reasons I prefer to use an external file published in assets so my question is:

Is it possible to publish an external js file with MyModuleAssets.php and register it later in the view independently from the other js assets, where needed?
In fact I need to close and reopen the dialog with other ids and so I need to register the js again several time.

Could someone give me an hint and maybe some pieces of the core code?

Thanks in advance

Luca

Answer (score 0):

Assets are published as a package. So if you want some JS/CSS to be registered somewhere and others in another situations, you should create different packages and register each of them when needed.

Comment: Actually you just rewrite what I was asking for.
Thanks anyway.